# Creating temporary Tables in stored Proceduresmysql

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures

this is my first post here, so im sorry for any mistakes or missing information you are expecting.
Im trying to create a Temporary Table in a procedure but somehow i keep getting errors (#1064 at `DECLARE l_coin_base_id INT UNSIGNED`), when i try to implement the procedure. I removed the whole Create temporary table part and it worked, so i believe my mistake is in this part.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE UPDATE_HISTORY()`

MODIFIES SQL DATA
BEGIN
    DECLARE l_c_pair INT DEFAULT (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 FROM pairList); 
    DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 1; 
    DECLARE l_now INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - 300;`

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp_history ENGINE = MEMORY AS(
SELECT
    active_pairList.base,
    active_pairList.peer,
    (active_history.highest_ask + active_history.highest_bid) / 2 AS price,
    active_history.buy_volume,
    active_history.sell_volume,
    active_history.trade_volume
FROM
    active_history
INNER JOIN
    active_pairList
ON
    active_history.sell_volume IS NOT NULL 
    AND active_history.buy_volume IS NOT NULL
    AND active_history.trade_volume IS NOT NULL
    AND active_history.timeStamp > l_now); 
    DECLARE l_coin_base_id INT UNSIGNED; 
    DECLARE l_coin_peer_id INT UNSIGNED; 
    DECLARE l_avg_price FLOAT UNSIGNED; 
    DECLARE l_sum_buy_volume FLOAT UNSIGNED; 
    DECLARE l_sum_sell_volume FLOAT UNSIGNED; 
    DECLARE l_sum_trade_volume FLOAT UNSIGNED; 
-- doing smth. --
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

If i try to execute the CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE part in a statement, im able to create the temporary table and its created correctly. Google doesnt know it either. (This is also my first time using join so maybe there is my mistake?).

I would be really thankfull for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't define variable in middle of the procedure. It should be after BEGIN.
So declare all variables in beginning of procedure.